# Loading nested resource from the classpath in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, classloader

Spring Boot 2.1.5.RELEASE here. I'm trying to load a resource from a `src/main/resources/images` directory. My best attempt thus far is:

```java
URL url = getClass().getResource("classpath:images/my_logo.png");
if (url == null) {
  log.warn("Hmmm not found...");
} else {
  log.info("Found it!");
}
```

At runtime the WARNing "*Hmmm not found...*" is printing, but the file is *absolutely* located at `src/main/resources/images/my_logo.png`. Where am I going awry?

Comment: Try with absolute path if it works them possibly your is still missed by Clasapath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are already using Spring, try using one of their resource loaders

```
URL url = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver( null ).getResource( "classpath:/images/my_logo.png" ).getURL();
```

Notice: I added a leading slash to the path.

**EDIT**: I did check on @duffymo's comment and it was correct. The leading slash is not necessary.

Comment: The path relative to src/main/resources should not need the leading slash.  I agree about the resource loaders.

Comment: Thanks guys! This works _without_ the leading slash!

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way to retrieve resources in Spring, but the [ResourceUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html) Javadoc is clear that the class is mainly for internal use.

```
String file = ResourceUtils.getFile("images/my_logo.png").getAbsolutePath();
```

Or by using `ClassPathResource`

```
URL clsPath =  new ClassPathResource("images/my_logo.png").getURL();
```